# Do I need a doctors letter for taking sertaline into the USA?

Tags: usa

I'm flying to the USA this month and I'm wondering if I need to have a doctors note to accompany my sertaline. I also have 2 epi pens as I suffer from severe anaphylaxis shock, I have already gotten a letter for this from my doctor. I'm carrying the original packaging for both of these and my repeat prescription form. I will place the epi pens  in a clear plastic bag as its a liquid.

In short my question is just do I need a doctors note to accompany the sertaline as well as the epi pens? Thank you!! :) sorry if I rambled on!

Comment: You may find these page helpful: CBP  https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1160  FDA https://www.fda.gov/consumers/consumer-updates/5-tips-traveling-us-medications "In general, you should have with you a valid prescription or doctor’s note—written in English—to bring medication to the U.S. The medication should be in its original container with the doctor’s instructions printed on the bottle. If you don’t have the original container, bring a copy of your prescription or a letter from your doctor explaining your condition and why you need this medication."